# Are there more materials about multiplicative sequence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I am reading the *Topological methods in algebraic geometry* by F. Hirzebruch. But I have some difficulties in understanding the multiplicative sequence. Are there other materials about in multiplicative sequences? Any recommendations will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: You're going to need to add some context. What is a multiplicative sequence?

Comment: You can try Fulton's Riemann-Roch algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Another reference for multiplicative sequences is $\S 19$ of Milnor & Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*.